# Most efficient way to maintain a 'set' in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have ~2 million rows or so of data, each row with an artificial PK, and two Id fields (so: PK, ID1, ID2). I have a unique constraint (and index) on ID1+ID2.

I get two sorts of updates, both with a distinct ID1 per update.

1. 100-1000 rows of all-new data (ID1 is new)
2. 100-1000 rows of largely, but not necessarily completely overlapping data (ID1 already exists, maybe new ID1+ID2 pairs)

What's the most efficient way to maintain this 'set'? Here are the options as I see them:

1. Delete all the rows with ID1, insert all the new rows (yikes)
2. Query all the existing rows from the set of new data ID1+ID2, only insert the new rows
3. Insert all the new rows, ignore inserts that trigger unique constraint violations

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of your listed solutions are functionally equivalent, so without more knowledge about what you want or need to accomplish, it's hard to say which is most appropriate.

1. You may lose data that you want or need to keep.
2. Based on the table schema that you mentioned, this should be reasonable.
3. This will only work if you perform each INSERT separately.

I'd suggest [2] based on the available info.

Comment: Yeah, there's tradeoffs, certainly -- basically all of them are acceptable, I'm just trying to minimize my pain re: cost of doing this work a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 (or 2008 R2), you can look at the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510625.aspx), something like:

```
MERGE INTO MyTable mt 
USING NewRows nr 
   ON mt.ID1 = nr.ID1 and mt.ID2 = nr.ID2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (ID1,ID2,<more columns>) VALUES (nr.ID1,nr.ID2,<other columns>);
```

Comment: Awesome, if I go with a stored procedure I'll look into that.